# How do I use cpulimit with ImageMagick?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, imagemagick

I am converting (using ImageMagick) a directory of image files (using a bash for loop in shell).

I notice that "convert" is taking up a large amount of CPU use (88% and up). However, If I try to limit it using cpulimit

`cpulimit -l 10 -e convert`

it responds

`Warning: no target process found. Waiting for it...`

even though it is visible in `ps` and `top`

Answer (score 1):

cpulimit looks for the process by looking at /proc/pppp/exe  (where pppp is the pid), which is a link to the executable, for some processes this does not contain the name you are expecting

I had the same problem with firefox-bin, ps gives:

```
dave     4117  3595  4 04:49 ?        00:11:54 /usr/lib/iceweasel/firefox-bin
```

but

```
ls -l /proc/4117/exe 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dave dave 0 Jan  9 13:50 /proc/4117/exe -> /usr/lib/xulrunner-10.0/xulrunner-stub
```

On my system, convert is /usr/bin/convert.im6 so:

```
cpulimit -l 10 -e convert.im6
```

works for me.

Comment: It finds the process, but then kills ImageMagick into Interruptable Sleep (ps -aux).

Comment: That's how cpulimit works, to suspends the process intermittently. I would just just run convert with nice, it will still use a lot of cpu, but give way to higher priority processes.